# How to generate and compile C++ code while the program is running?

Tags: c++, compilation

So basically what I need isn't a specific code (of course that would be great), but just an idea and methods on how to achieve my goal.

1) I have to create a program in C++ , which generates a little example of C++ code, that is each time a bit different. (This causes no problems for me, I will use a template and randomize some variables in the code, which will make it unique every time.)

2) I will display the generated code and the user will have to type in, what he thinks the code prints out.

**And here is where the problems start**:

3) I have to take the generated code and compile it somehow to get a string with the text that the program would have printed out.

4) And then compare the string with what the user has typed in.

So the step 3) is where I stop and can't figure it out without help... I was thinking to write the generated code in a function of a .cpp file and then call that function, but I couldn't get it to work, so I started to think, I should ask an expert, maybe there are some other methods or ideas how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Write the .cpp file
2. invoke the compiler (or make or equivalent build system)
3. if compilation fails, presumably display the errors?
4. if compilation succeeds, run the resulting program and display the output

It's probably simplest to wrap 2/3/4 into a script, and invoke that with `system` or `popen`. The script can make sure the filenames are unique, fold stderr into stdout, etc. etc.

Your running program isn't really interacting with the compiled code, just reading the output, so keeping it as a seperate process is probably easiest.  The script can add some markup to help you distinguish compiler output/errors from the program output.

---

I haven't written a batch file for years, but once you know how to run your compiler from the command line ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)), you can write a script to:

1. compile a `.cpp` file
2. execute the resulting `.exe`
3. redirect its output to a file

then, in C++ you just need to save the code to the `.cpp` file the script expects, execute the script like `system("myScript.bat")`, and then read the output file.

If you don't want to write a seperate batch script, you can just call `system` once to invoke the compiler, and again to execute the resulting `.exe`.

Comment: This sounds promising enough, but stil, i have no idea how to invoke a compiler. Actualy thats all i need, i need to compile a nother .cpp file while executing the main one... can you be more specific please?

Comment: How you invoke your compiler is platform-specific (and compiler specific). Can you tell me what platform, compiler and build system you're using now?

Comment: I'm working on 64bit win 7, using MS visual studio 2010 Express, i realy can't tell you much more(i don't know). I havent changed anything everything is default, hope this is enough

Comment: ... amended answer with some more details.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Now i just have to figure out HOW to compile the cpp trough the command line and then create a batch file.

Comment: @krishkule MSDN to the rescue: [Walkthrough: Compiling a Native C++ Program on the Command Line (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a way to script c++. Have a look at http://www.softintegration.com/ or this stackoverflow question [Any tutorial for embedding Clang as script interpreter into C++ Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224485/any-tutorial-for-embedding-clang-as-script-interpreter-into-c-code).

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this but it is free and also does not compile but interpret. Very suitable for your problem, worth a shot...

http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint

Answer (score 0):

why dont you compile the generated code standalone using system() call?
system("g++ temp.cpp -o temp.exe); --something of this sort and then based on the return value
you can run temp.exe again like system("temp.exe"); Ofcourse you can print the output from temp.exe to a file and read that file to get the output of temp.exe to your current program..

Answer (score 0):

Would something like [Geordi](http://weegen.home.xs4all.nl/eelis/geordi/) work?

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the c++ compiler just like you'd invoke any external tool. E.g. `system("g++ test.cpp")` or use popen or whatever else is offered by your platform.

You could also look into integrating a library that implements a compiler into your program. For that you might want to look into clang and llvm.