# Generate and run LLVM code from native C/C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, llvm, clang

Is it possible to do these things from a native `C` or `C++`-compiled program (gcc):

1. Call `clang` and compile given `C` code of a function, passed as `const char *`.
2. Obtain a pointer and run it in the LLVM virtual machine.
3. Acquire the result in the native program and continue.

How?

Comment: I think a better more descriptive title is needed to catch attention of more SO users.

Comment: @Nawaz Good point, I've corrected it now.

Comment: Of course it is possible. See http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling for example.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224485/any-tutorial-for-embedding-clang-as-script-interpreter-into-c-code.

Comment: Have a look at Cling. For an example of a function in a C++ interpreter you can check this article: http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/08/14/cling-cpp-11-interpreter/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a minimalistic example, see [Clang interpreter](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/examples/clang-interpreter/main.cpp).

[Cling](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling) is bit more practical example of such an approach.

Comment: @James, it is an interactive C++ interpreter based on LLVM and Clang and optionally integrated into ROOT. Sort of a replacement for their older Cint thing.

Comment: This is what I posted below the code. Cling implements JIT which is offered by llvm, see this link on how to use it: http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl4.html